# Is it possible to position an element with absolute positioning relative to a container if it is OUTSIDE the container?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Lets say you have two divs:

```
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

`div1` has relative positioning and `div2` has absolute positioning. Can `div2` be positioned as if it was inside `div1` either using CSS or pure Javascript?

Comment: You can't do it with CSS, but you can set any absolute positioning you want with Javascript.  It will have to be positioned on top of div1 to appear to be inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JavaScript.

You have to wrap divs inside parent container with **position: absolute** and set div2 position to absolute as well.

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="div1"></div>
    <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

And then using javascript:

```
var div1 = document.querySelector(".div1");
var div2 = document.querySelector(".div2");

div2.style.left = div1.offsetLeft + 'px';
div2.style.top = div1.offsetTop + 'px';
```

See [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/17jdu8jt/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this fits your question? http://jsfiddle.net/bghxmm3o/

Absolute div2 (blue) positioned into relative div1 (red).

It's just CSS:

```
#d1 {
    position:relative;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
}
#d2 {
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:50px;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no, it depends on how you build it and the surrounding HTML. If you put this code directly inside the body then yes, because the body would then be the parent element of both .div1 and .div2. And if you didn't know it already positioning something absolute positions the element to the top left corner of the "closest" relative positioned parent element. (Hard to explain in text)

But if you were to have other HTML outside these two div elements, then you would need a parent element with a position relative.

So as an example:

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="div1"></div>
    <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

.box1 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

.box2 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
}
```